# Could Elastic Beanstalk connect to database in EC2?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running some codes and store the data into mongodb.

And I write a django project(mysite) and deploy to a Elastic Beanstalk.

But the project(mysite) a need to show the data (query from the mongodb in EC2 )

So I have a wabsite in Elastic Beanstalk,and I need to connect to an EC2 mongodb to get the data

Is tehere anyway to do this??  Please help me. thank you!

here is mysite/settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 's_database',
        'HOST': '1.2.3.4',  #EC2's HOST  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly connect to a database in EC2 Instance ( MongoDB ) from an app in ElasticBeanstalk.

Ensure the following are done

1. You need open the Security Group for the MongoDB Port - TCP - 27017
2. Enable Remote host connection in your Mongo Instance

Another alternative you may consider is to try DynamoDB.

Comment: First of all,Thank you.   ````Enable Remote host connection in your Mongo Instance ```` how to do this?  I set the security Group:27017  And my setting 'HOST': '1.2.3.4',  'PORT':'27017' don't know how to do next ?

Comment: You need to modify the MongoDB conf file -you need to change the bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 with bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 to allow connections to MongoDB from remote hosts. For more info about the conf file - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/